# How I get coordinates with drawing?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Folks,

I have this code https://gist.github.com/2473387

But, how do I get the coordinates of the polygon drawn?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggest to add 'polygoncomplete' listener on [DrawingManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManager) and get coordinates from polygon [MVCArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
    console.log(coordinates);
});
```